# restoring image back to same position after tombstoning in WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I m using MouseDragElementBehavior in my WP7 application to drag an image down the canvas. I m able to get the coordinates (X,Y positions) after the image dragging. But I want to retain the  same image position after tombstoning also.

```
    private void MouseDragElementBehavior_Dragging(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        Point currentPos = e.GetPosition(image1);
        if (currentPos.X < 190)
        {
            double targetOffset = 700;

            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
            animation.EasingFunction = new CircleEase();
            animation.Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
            animation.From = TextScroll.AnimatableOffset;
            animation.To = targetOffset;

            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, TextScroll);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("(AnimatableScrollViewer.AnimatableOffset)"));
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
            storyboard.Children.Add(animation);

            storyboard.Begin();
        }

        App app = (App)Application.Current;
        app.current_X = currentPos.X.ToString();
        app.current_Y = currentPos.Y.ToString();

        TextScroll.AnimatableOffset = -700;
    }
```

I have stored and retrived the  values from isolated storage for tombstoning.

```
    private void LoadSettings()
    {
        var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        current_X = settings["Xpos"].ToString();
        current_Y = settings["Ypos"].ToString();
    }

    private void SaveSettings()
    {
        var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        settings.Add("Xpos", current_X);
        settings.Add("Ypos",current_Y);
        settings.Save();
    }
```

Now I would like to use the values to position the image at the same coordinates as before tombstoning. I dont know how to position the image with the X and Y coordinates provided.

Here is the XAML code where I use the image.

```
       <Canvas Margin="12,0,3,-834" Grid.Row="1">
        <Image Height="800" Source="37.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Width="480" Canvas.Left="-11" x:Name="image1">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <el:MouseDragElementBehavior ConstrainToParentBounds="True" Dragging="MouseDragElementBehavior_Dragging" />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Image>
    </Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `Point currentPos = e.GetPosition(image1);` is getting the position of the mouse relative to the image.  Maybe you want to get the position relative to the canvas instead?

Or, you can use this to get the position within the canvas:

```
canvas1.GetLeft(image1);
canvas1.GetTop(image1);
```

Then, you can set the position of something within a canvas like this:

```
canvas1.SetLeft(image1, x); 
canvas1.SetTop(image1, y);
```

To do that, you would need to name your Canvas:

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas1" Margin="12,0,3,-834" Grid.Row="1">
```

Comment: if I get the X and Y coordinates from Point currentPos = e.GetPosition(image1); How do I set back the image to the same X ,Y coordinates